# Would this SEO question be a good fit to migrate here?

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question, stack-overflow

I ran across this question on Stack Overflow: [Stop Search Engine crawling of “tel:” links?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36228823/5764553)

It needs editing, but it appears to me that it would be on topic here, because it has to do with SEO. It is not about coding JavaScript (apparently, somebody didn't tag it correctly). It is not specific to the OP's site, in my opinion.

It *might* be a little about HTML. I'm not entirely clear on the nature of the problem. But I do see some questions here, [such as this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/82782/60615), which seem to have a similar level of HTML-ness involved.

I can't tell if it's a duplicate. I did a search for `tel` links and didn't see anything that addressed the problem.

Is the question fit to be migrated?

Comment: Nice catch!! BTW- I am glad you are here.

Comment: All yours: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91883/stop-search-engine-crawling-of-tel-links

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would be a good fit here, too. However the question is too old to be migrated. However, if someone were to re-ask it here I would think it would be kept open.

Comment: 6 days ago is too old to be migrated? What is the limit?

Comment: Oh, duh. Misread it. That can be migrated. I'd say flag it and see what happens. The omre that flag it the more likely we get it.